# AspNetWebHooks and notifying to webhooks outside of a MVC or WebAPI controller

Tags: c#, webhooks

I am using the libary https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetWebHooks to implement custom webhooks.
I use both the MVC and WebAPI controller extensions to call the NotifyAsync() function to send webhooks. I have a WCF callback function I want to call NotifyAsync(). How do I go about sending the webhook since this is not a controller? My question is how do I get access to the web hook manager? Looking at the WebApi controller extension it uses the below code to get access.

```
        // How do I get access to the webhook manager? 
        var manager = controller.Configuration.DependencyResolver.GetManager();
        return await manager.NotifyAllAsync(notifications, predicate);
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok after much trolling through the library code this works

```
    // this can be used outside of a MVC or WebAPI controller
    public static async Task NotifyAsync(string action, object data)
    {
        var logger = CommonServices.GetLogger();
        var store = CustomServices.GetStore();
        var sender = CustomServices.GetSender(logger);
        var manager = new WebHookManager(store, sender, logger);
        var notifications = new NotificationDictionary[] { new NotificationDictionary(action, data) };
        await manager.NotifyAllAsync(notifications, null);
    }
```